# Multiple SELECT with LEFT JOIN to order results

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables, looking like this:

#### Table 1

```
id | name |          date
---+------+---------------------
 1 | zaak |  2016-08-03 11:37:40  -- top 1 dates, name #5
 2 | aap  |  2016-08-01 11:40:35  
 3 | corn |  2016-08-02 11:42:16  -- top 3 dates, name #3
 4 | quar |  2016-08-02 11:42:28  -- top 2 dates, name #4
 5 | alfa |  2016-07-04 11:44:29
```

#### Table 2

```
id | open | name  | name_id | type
---+------+-------+---------+-----
 1 |   1  | aap   |    2    |   2  -- type = 2, open = 1 : 1
 2 |   1  | quar  |    4    |   2  -- type = 2, open = 1 : 1
 3 |   1  | quar  |    4    |   2  -- type = 2, open = 1 : 1
 4 |   1  | dinky |    1    |   1  -- type = 1, open = 1 : NULL
 5 |   2  | quar  |    1    |   1  -- type = 1, open = 2 : NULL
```

The result I need is `id` and `name` from table 1 and `open` from table 2.

### The requirements:

- from table 1: select the newest three by `date`
- order those three by `name` from A - Z
- from table 2: select `open`

  - IF `name` not there return `NULL`
  - IF `type` <> 2  return `NULL`
  - IF `open` <> 1  return `NULL`
  - ELSE              return 1

With a lot of trial and error I constructed this query:

```
-- get id, name and open only once
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id , t1.name , t3.open 

-- select names from table 1, order them by date and return first 3
FROM (SELECT id , name FROM table1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3) AS t1

-- get open from table 2 IF id is there, open = 1 and type =2
LEFT JOIN ( ( SELECT open , name_id  
              FROM table2 
              WHERE open=1 AND type=2
            ) AS t3
          ) 
ON t1.id = t3.name_id 

-- order by name from A-Z
ORDER BY t1.name ASC
```

The result I get is correct:

```
id | name | open
---+------+-----
 3 | corn | NULL  (correct)
 4 | quar | 1     (correct)
 1 | zaak | NULL  (correct)
```

As my knowledge of MYSQL is limited, I wonder

- would this query always return the desired result? (the data in the tables is limited at the moment and I have to change values by hand to see different results, so testing all variations proves a bit difficult)
- is there anything I could improve on this query, or should I construct an entirely different query? (as triple `SELECT` to get the desired result seems a bit overdone)

Comment: **Try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @BCdotWEB. If you have any suggestions, please? I've been thinking about a good title for quite a while, as I suspected this one was a bit too cryptic, but couldn't come up with something that made any sense. But I will try to formulate something else.

Comment: I didn't get how "ELSE return 1" is meet here. besides that I think the query is correct.

Comment: @montelof, it seems to come from `SELECT open ... WHERE open=1`.  If it's not obvious, then that's something to pick up at review.

Answer (score 6):

First of all you don't need so many subqueries. all of your code can be done in given way

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, t1.name, t2.open
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.name_id AND t2.open = 1 AND type = 2
ORDER BY t1.date DESC, t1.name ASC LIMIT 3
```

Works exactly the way you want it, plus is almost 3 times faster on my machine. (0.0012 seconds vs 0.0034)

for additional reading on subqueries and joins https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856164/sql-joins-vs-sql-subqueries-performance
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query

Second point is that I think you should not be storing name value in *table2*. i don't know your project requirements or specifics but one of the major point of relational databases is to diversify data and avoid copies of the same data in different places.

*table2* is connected with *table1* with *name_id* which means it indirectly provides name value and i would suggest removing that column from *table2* if it's not absolutely neccessery for your project, or it would mean u should rewrite  big portion of your code.

Comment: Thanks, this works and indeed is a bit quicker. As for your second point, call it laziness but table 2 is called upon about 20 times more than table 1, and as I have the values at hand when inserting a record, it's just so I do not have to join with table 1 all the time to get the name. Maybe bad practice, but it makes life a bit more simple :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need subquery `t3` - I think it can be written as (untested):

```
-- get id, name and open only once
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id , t1.name , table2.open 

-- select names from table 1, order them by date and return first 3
FROM (SELECT id , name FROM table1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3) AS t1

-- get open from table 2 IF id is there, open = 1 and type =2
LEFT JOIN table2
ON t1.id = table2.name_id
WHERE open=1 AND type=2

-- order by name from A-Z
ORDER BY t1.name ASC
```

I don't think it's possible to avoid the `t1` subquery, as we need to sort by date there, but by name for the final result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this isn't working. The query returns only one name, where 3 is correct in my example.